# R summing factors

Tags: r, sum, r-factor

I split some data according to  factors like:

```
 a <- factor(data$fact)
 b <- split(data,a)
```

Now I would like to add some of the factor together e.g.

```
tot <- b$A+b$B
```

but I'm getting the following error,

```
"sum" not meaningful for factors
```

Any help would be great.

aaa  val1  val2 ...
aaa
bbb
bbb
ccc
ccc

Now if I split into factors I have three. But I want for example aaa and ccc to be considered together. This meas that the value in the other column should be summed up.

Thanks

Comment: A factor indicates that you are working with categorical values. It makes no sense to add (sum) categorical variables. Can you describe (in natural language, not code) what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: I simply splitted the data into factors but I need to sum some of these together. Nothing else.

Comment: OK, I see. Now you have one list for `apples` and one list for `pears`. You still can't sum these together. Nothing else.

Comment: Ok so if I have a list of apples, pear, banana and  strawberry and at the end I want (apples+pear), banana and strawberry I can't do it. Clear

Comment: What do you mean by (apples+pears)? Do you want to have one factor instead of these two? Or maybe your factors are numbers? Give us an example of `b$A`, `b$B` and `tot` value that you wish to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new factor variable before splitting:

```
# Make up some data
df = data.frame(Cases = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace=TRUE),
                Set1 = 1:10, Set2 = 11:20)
# Duplicate your cases column
df$Cases_2 = df$Cases
# Create a new set of factor levels
levels(df$Cases_2) <- ifelse(levels(df$Cases_2) %in% c("A","B"), 
                             "AB", levels(df$Cases_2))
temp = split(df[-c(1, 4)], df$Cases_2)
temp
# $AB
#   Set1 Set2
# 3    3   13
# 5    5   15
# 6    6   16
# 8    8   18
# 
# $C
#   Set1 Set2
# 4    4   14
# 9    9   19
# 
# $D
#    Set1 Set2
# 2     2   12
# 7     7   17
# 10   10   20
# 
# $E
#   Set1 Set2
# 1    1   11
```

Then use `lapply` to calculate `colSums`:

```
lapply(temp, colSums)
# $AB
# Set1 Set2 
#   22   62 
# 
# $C
# Set1 Set2 
#   13   33 
# 
# $D
# Set1 Set2 
#   19   49 
# 
# $E
# Set1 Set2 
#    1   11
```

Comment: @g256, I've added the method for column sums for you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to combine the resulting data frames using `rbind`:

```
tot <- rbind(b$A, b$B)
```